# Highcharts - Highlight above part of column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

All,

I have a requirement i want to highlight the above part of bars column chart. To be more expressive I  am attaching the image what exactly I need to do. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaJ4y.png)

Thank you in advance

**Edited :**

What I did is have given 2 series and stacked them.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Background',
            data: [250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250],
            color: 'rgba(94, 143, 184, 0.5)',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Actual',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            color: '#ffffff',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }

        }]
```

What I am looking for is much neater solution where I can use only 1 series and use some control for Highchart where it can fill the remaining part to full length.

Comment: Please add to your question what you have tried so far...

Comment: @xFlowDev updated my question.

Comment: you can try like these by defining one series full as 100 in percent and then deduct second series from first. you can find fiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/L02awbfe/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature like this, you can [extend Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) method, in this case - `seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawPoints` - but it would be harder than just creating non-responsive second series.

On load event, you can add that series with disabled mouse tracking, etc. - so it behaves like background.

```
  series.chart.addSeries({
    data: data,
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    grouping: false,
    color: 'rgba(94, 143, 184, 0.5)',
    zIndex: -1
  }, false);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tcwmp92y/

Comment: Thanks. That helped alot.